# Multiple dead ends while looking for how to implement authorization with JSF2 on JBoss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jboss, jaas

Let's start by saying the obvious, I browsed many SO questions but with no luck all of them doesn't discuss my specifics case/need.

I have a **USER** table (**email**,**password**(plain_text_for_now),**role**(admin,mod,user)).

**1)** I'm using JSF2, and using JBOSS wildfly as my server, for services EJB/JPA mapping in another separate project *(I already created my data source, and almost finished my application,what i need now is implementing security)*

**2)** in my web pages I have **/login.xhtml; /admin/*.xhtml; /mod/*.xhtml; /user/*.xhtml**.

**I want that after a user get logged in to have only access to the folder that match his role!.** .here is what I found after too much digging:

- I need to create a Jboss Realm which I did and then edit my web.xml file ie: https://developer.jboss.org/message/640619#640619#640619 . for some reasons this didn't work and I get rerouted to the error.xhtml page (login fail)
- Other solutions that I found but I didn't try them out yet, is to create a filtering servlet that will handle the requests....

Obviously I am kinda lost between SO answers DOES NOT treat my specific case (many solutions consist of using some tutorials that works only on glassfish) and trying to figure out what my next step should be, many tutorials and none of them is specifics / clear / target my dev environment